# Vue create child component instance manually, set parent or not will influence child instance set prop value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

1. code:

```js
// Child Component
var TestComp = Vue.component('TestComp', {
    template: `<div>Child Component Prop Value : {{text}} </div>`,
    // child component prop --> text
    props: {
        text: {
            default: 'init prop'
        }
    }
});


// Parent
var vm = window.vm = new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    template: "#app",
    mounted() {
        this.createSubComp();
    },
    data() {return {}},
    methods: {
        createSubComp() {
            var that = this;
            var copy = Vue.extend(TestComp);
            var instance = window.vmsub = new copy({
                // here, remove comment
                // parent: that
            });
            // add or remove comment above, cause different result 
            instance.text = 'pass child component prop';
            instance.$mount();
            this.$el.append(instance.$el);
        }
    },
    components: {
        TestComp
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="app">
  <div style="height: 100; border: 1px solid red; overflow: auto;">
  </div>
</script>
```

2. child component: TestComp, it has a prop attribute named 'text',
   and parent component's method named 'createSubComp' is tring to create child component instance

   When 'parent: that' is been commented like right now, 'instance.text = 'xx'' executes success and throw none exception.

   But when i remove 'parent: that's comment,   'instance.text = 'xx'' throws an exception:
   Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders,
   Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "text"

   I want to add the code 'parent: that' so that the child instance can show in vue-devtools.
   I want to know what makes different result when i add/remove comment.

   Bad English... thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach to Vue components look like some workaround to achieve something very special...

But if that's not the case, the more simple, Vue approach to implement that will look more like that, just let Vue.js do what it built to do:

```js
// Child Component
var TestComp = Vue.component('TestComp', {
    template: `<div>Child Component Prop Value : {{text}} </div>`,
    // child component prop --> text
    props: {
        text: {
            default: 'init prop'
        }
    }
});


// Parent
var vm = window.vm = new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    template: '<test-comp text="pass child component props" />', // passing props to child component, using template
    data() {return {}},
    components: {
        TestComp
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="app">
  <div style="height: 100; border: 1px solid red; overflow: auto;">
  </div>
</script>
```

Vue.js will create the child component for you

Comment: Thanks! I add more description

I can understand your code.           
But because i have several vue pages that use same child component, so i try to create child component instance manually to avoid existing same code.

Now, i can create child component  instance 

But i find that i add or remove the code : 'parent: that' will cause different result
If i remove the code 'parent: that', i can change child instant prop value free

Comment: Truth is, that is very hard to me to debug your code above, because It's doing things that I don't know their results, your code looks like trying very hard to do what Vue.js internals has to do automatically for you. You can use same child component at many pages + places in your app, each time creating the child instance as I show you at the `template` propery, and freely pass each time different text to the child prop